# How to show value entered in textbox in jquery datatable as column value

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a html form and 3 text boxs in it. How to show the values entered by user in textboxes as data in jquery datatables.

```
columns: [{
  title: "Field",
  data: $("#newname").val()
}, {
  title: "New Value",
  data: $("#Allocated").val()
}, {
  title: "Previous Value",
  data: $("#newAllocated").val()
}]
```

This is the coloumn in datatable definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for long time I got the solution for that. Instead of giving the identifier in data we need to give that seperatly. The below code works for me.

```
var allocated = $("#Allocated").val()
var updated = $("#newAllocated").val()
var d ="Allocation Amount" 
columns: [
{
title: "Field",
},
{
title: "New Value",
},
{
title: "Previous Value",
}],
data: [[d, updated, allocated]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting value by it's name like this...

```
$('input:text[name=yourTextBoxName]').val();
```